# Bash script copy a files

Tags: bash

I have two folders: one contains .dwg files and the other .pdf files. The tree in my folders is different.

How can I copy a PDF near a DXF that has the same name? For example I have to copy the file `/1/2/3/1.pdf` to `/6/4/5/5/` where I found the file `1.dxf`

I ve tried this :

```
for DIR in $source
do
        for LISTE in `find $DIR  -type f -name '*.PDF' -or -name '*.pdf' `
        do
                find $dest -type f -name {} -exec ****** {} \;
        done
done
```

My problem is I don't know how to get a name from `find $dest -type f`.

Comment: There's `basename` to strip the directory path, but I didn't fully understand what's the problem beside this

Comment: I suggest you look at [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9496/33747) to really understand how tricky it is to move files with the shell. It can be a good learning exercise, but to me a scripting language is always better for this kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

*"My problem is I don't know how to get a name from find $dest -type f."*

Use the `-printf` option of `find`:

```
find ${dest} -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

See [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

> ```
> -printf format
>        True;  print  format  on  the standard output, 
>        interpreting `\' escapes and `%' directives.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>   %f     File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).
> ```